# NetBeans 8.1 - remote GlassFish 4.1.1

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I have a remote debian 8 server with GlassFish 4.1.1 running fine.
 - Admin console through port 4848 works fine.
 - Deployments through admin console work fine.

I have a local NetBeans 8.1 I.D.E and local glassfish-4.1.1 to test applications.

Now I want to bind remote GlassFish server to my I.D.E. to deploy applications and test it remotely in one click.

I did the regular process, running NetBeans as administrator :

Services>Servers>Add Server>Remote Domain

And filled up  :

- domain with domain1 (default glassfish domain actually running)
- host with my server ip
- DAS port : 4848
- HTTP port : 8080 (default)
- userName with glassfish admin user
- password with glassfish admin password.

Now the server is added to NetBeans, though showing not running.

Right-click>view console says "Server must be running to view admin console"

Deploying a test app print error : 
"Deployment error: Starting of server GlassFish Server is not supported. Please, start the server manually. See the server log for details."

How to success to bind NetBeans I.D.E. to a remote glassfish server?
I tried running NetBeans as administrator.
I'm running remote GlassFish with enable-secure-admin.

Comment: Any luck with getting this to work with 8.x yet?  Have you tried this with payara?  I'm getting the same issues...this seems so basic.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forgot to enable secure-admin.

Try the following:

```
asadmin change-admin-password
asadmin enable-secure-admin
asadmin stop-domain
asadmin start-domain
```

**See also:**

- [NetBeans Wiki - Remote Glassfish](http://wiki.netbeans.org/RemoteGlassFish4)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running remote GlassFish with enable-secure-admin, then you need to make sure you can connect to your remote server by verifying it from command line or browser in case other problem such as firewall etc.